# How to disable Interceptor in exported function?

Tags: angular, localization, interceptor, angular-http-interceptors, ngx-translate

I use ngx-translator for localization. When I am trying to read json-files with localization that stores in local folder, I receiving an error HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 404, statusText: "Not Found", url: "http:/host.com/api/assets/i18n/en.json", ok: false, …}. I thing that problem is in Interceptor that I use in my app.

```
// app.module.ts
export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, 'assets/i18n/', '.json');
}
```

How can I disable interceptor in this function? I tried to set header as X-Skip-Interceptor, but It doesn't help.

Answer (score 9):

You can use HttpBackend

> When injected, HttpBackend dispatches requests directly to the
>   backend, without going through the interceptor chain.

In your app.module.ts  pass HttpBackend as deps and not HttpClient

```
TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: (HttpLoaderFactory),
        deps: [HttpBackend],
      },
    }),
```

And Modify HttpLoaderFactory as below

```
export function HttpLoaderFactory(handler: HttpBackend) {

    const http = new HttpClient(handler);

    return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/i18n/', '.json');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Read your local json data like below

private _productURL = 'api/products/products.json';    
getProducts(): Observable<any> {
        return this._http.get(this._productURL).map((response : Response) => <any> response.json())
        .do(data =>console.log(JSON.stringify(data))).catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy fix for this. You can just skip the translation file as preceding.

```
function MSALAngularConfigFactory(): MsalAngularConfiguration {
  return {
    popUp: false,
    consentScopes: [
      environment.backendConfig.resourceScope
    ],
    protectedResourceMap: [
      [environment.backendConfig.url, [environment.backendConfig.resourceScope]],
      ['./assets/i18n/*.json', null]
    ],
  };
}
```

We set this in the `protectedResourceMap`. If you get an error as "ERROR in src/app/app.module.ts:47:30 - error TS2322: Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string[]'." use `as any`.

```
protectedResourceMap: [
      [environment.backendConfig.url, [environment.backendConfig.resourceScope]],
      ['./assets/i18n/*.json', null as any]
    ]
```

And just incase your images are not loading in your site, that may be an issue with your CSS. Change the `background` styles from `background: url(../../assets/img/background.svg)` to `background: url(/assets/img/background.svg)`. You can read more in this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/2839).